# cell View returns nil on app running

Tags: ios, swift, custom-cell, uitableview

I've used the next code for adding subview into UIView in the custom cell:

```
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 36, height: 36))
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "addNewSkill.png")

cell.countView.addSubview(imageView)
```

where:

```
@IBOutlet var countView: UIView!
```

on my custom cell file. When I run my app it crashes with the next error in logs:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
Printing description of cell.countView:
(UIView!) countView = nil
```

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Why are you adding cell.countView.addSubview(imageView)? Why not just use cell.addSubview(imageView)?

Comment: @user2893289 because I want to add it into this view

Comment: Where you add imageView

Comment: Your tableView is in your view right? Isn´t that enough? You add a tableView to a view not a cell.

Comment: @user2893289 tableView or imageView?

Comment: @vienvu i did not understand your question

Comment: Your tableView is in your view and you should add the imageView to your cell only, so cell.addSubview(imageView) is enough.

Comment: 1. Do you use Storyboards? If yes, try to use Cell Prototypes for custom cells.
2. How do you create cell? Do you use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` method for creating cell? Did you register you custom cell for your tableview?

Comment: @user2893289 but I want to add it into view, exactly! I know that it's enough

Comment: @radya yes, I created a xib and later registered it

Comment: ah @OrkhanAlizade I am asking where you add imageView :D

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the crash from happening by safely unwrapping `cell.countView` with an if let statement.

```
if let countv = cell.countView {
    countv.addSubview(imageView)
}
```

You will still have to do some debugging to see why you are getting a nil value there though.

Comment: In this case it won't add my imageView at all

Comment: Its not possible to guess what causes the nil with simply watching your tiny code. You must find the root cause as I have already pointed in answer...

Comment: How I did say, it doesn't run at all

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is here .

[image]